System suddenly stops working and does not boot anymore
While I was using it, the system stop working. The last thing that I did was to copy a large file as sudo to the same directory where pg_restore should be residing (but I don't remember where exactly). I don't know if just this could corrupt everything.
After booting not successful I tried recovery mode. Run fsck but it showed me still many errors.
When I go to recovery mode I see this:

Do you have any ideas how to solve it before I format it?
